# Tabs in Wordpress, with content visible on page load

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs

On a Wordpress site I am trying to get tabs working which display content of custom post types. It is almost working except that on the first visit (or page refresh) the content of the last post type is not displayed. It appears when the link of the tab is clicked.
In HTML in which I created first the tabs work fine.

Does anyone know how to get the content of the last post type to display when the page is visited?

Thank you.

The original HTML:

```
<div class="row collapse">
<div class="medium-3 columns">
<ul class="tabs vertical" id="example-vert-tabs" data-tabs>
  <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1v" aria-selected="true">Case 1</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2v">Case 2</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel3v">Case 3</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel4v">Case 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="medium-9 columns">
<div class="tabs-content vertical" data-tabs-content="example-vert-tabs">
  <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1v">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/eee/ff0000?text=Foto" alt="" class="floatleft">
    <h3>Case 1 titel</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <p>Meer weten? <a href="#">Vraag om de details van deze case</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2v">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/eee/ff0000?text=Foto" alt="" class="floatleft">
    <h3>Case 2 titel</h3>
    <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus.</p>
    <p>Meer weten? <a href="#">Vraag om de details van deze case</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel3v">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/eee/ff0000?text=Foto" alt="" class="floatleft">
    <h3>Case 3 titel</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <p>Meer weten? <a href="#">Vraag om de details van deze case</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel4v">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/eee/ff0000?text=Foto" alt="" class="floatleft">
    <h3>Case 4 titel</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <p>Meer weten? <a href="#">Vraag om de details van deze case</a></p>
  </div>    
 </div>
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
            <div class="medium-3 columns">                              
                    <ul class="tabs vertical" id="example-vert-tabs" data-tabs>

            <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'cases' ); ?>
            <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
            <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


                  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-selected="true"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>

      <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>

            <!-- end medium-3 columns --> </div>

            <div class="medium-9 columns">
                  <div class="tabs-content vertical" data-tabs-content="example-vert-tabs">


     <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'cases' ); ?>
            <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
            <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="tabs-panel" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>


    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>
        <h1>Nog geen Cases</h1>
     <?php endif; ?>
                         <!-- end tabs-content vertical --> </div> 

                 <!-- end medium-9 columns --> </div>

     <!-- end row collapse --></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can like this and i am using Bootstrap for the tabs:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-bordered">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">All Topics</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Classic</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Relationships</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Communication</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">Business</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu6">Wellness</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu7">Fear</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
           <!-- <h3>All Topics</h3>-->
            <?php
            $catquery = new WP_Query('cat=3&posts_per_page=-1');
            while ($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class='posts-inner-section'>
                    <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="post-author">
                        <?php
                        echo'<p>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Post_writer', true) . '</p>';
                        $posttags = get_the_tags();
                        if ($posttags) {
                            foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
                                $tag_link = get_term_link($tag);
                                echo '<a class="d-none" href="' . $tag_link . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="byline vcard"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="blog-sgare-btn"><a href="#">Share</a></div>
                    <?php /*?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php */?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
           <!-- <h3>Classic</h3> -->
           <?php
            $catquery = new WP_Query('cat=8&posts_per_page=-1');
            while ($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class='posts-inner-section'>
                    <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="post-author">
                        <?php
                        echo'<p>' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Post_writer', true) . '</p>';
                        $posttags = get_the_tags();
                        if ($posttags) {
                            foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
                                $tag_link = get_term_link($tag);
                                echo '<a class="d-none" href="' . $tag_link . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="byline vcard"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="blog-sgare-btn"><a href="#">Share</a></div>
                    <?php /*?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php */?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Xabby,
Thank you for the quick response. The site is using Foundation by Zurb and that is working for me. 
It is more an issue me not knowing how do this in a Wordpress template.

What I understand is that the "is-active" class needs to be added to the active tab.
See the original HTML  <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1v">

So in Wordpress if an tab is selected the "is-active" class should be added to only that tab.

Comment: So right now its not adding Active class on click of any tab?

Comment: You can manually add class to the current tab that is clicked like this:

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tab").click(function () {
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");   
});
});

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure where to add this

Comment: Just add this Jquery in your footer.php and change the classes according to your own html

Comment: Thank you, will try this

Comment: Feeling really stupid but I can't get this to work.  I don't understand Jquery.
I have added this to the footer.php :
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { $(".tab").click(function () { $(".tab").removeClass("active"); $(this).addClass("is-active")   </script>

And edited the html to this:  (added active)
<div class="tabs-panel active" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div> 

To what should UI change the .tab to?

Comment: To be clear, the content of the first tab should be visible when the page loads.
See the original html in which it works 
<div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1v">...

Help is appreciated

Comment: Thank you for the help. Found another solution. I got i solved by rewriting the PHP code.

Comment: The solution:<?php   $i = 0;
   $args = array('post_type' => 'cases' ); ?>
                <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
                <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    $i = $i + 1;
    ?>
                        <div class="tabs-panel <?php if($i == 1){ ?>is-active<?php } ?>" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>               
  <?php endwhile; ?>
        
  <?php else: ?>
         <h1>Nog geen Cases</h1>
         <?php endif; ?>